# Simple 2D collision detection with vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, animation, geometry

I am trying to create collision algorithm and implement him in my Win32 2D GUI app. 
The task is that i got one vector that determinate mid-bottom of .bmp image and four more vectors in position of rhombus. I wanted to make it work so algorithm know if image is coming from left, right, up or bottom. There are a lot of tutorials over internet about collision detection of rectangle, circle and distance calculation but i am having difficulties in applying them for rhombus. There is also something called [axis-aligned bounding](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131833/when_two_hearts_collide_.php?print=1) but i think it is for 3d vectors. I am very weak when it comes to this topic, so if there is any skilled C++ programmer who could direct me to some good e-book that mention this topic or if the code is small maybe type it out. I tried doing iteration of X,Y coordinates over ABCD whole rhombus and failed miserably.

Thanks everyone who help.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Is this homework? (It's perfectly fine if it is, but it should be tagged [tag:homework] then) and 2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: Axis-aligned bounding boxes (AABB for short) are useful for 2d as well as 3d.  The idea is to surround a complicated object with a simple shape that is easy to check for collisions.  Then, if the bounding boxes *don't* collide, you don't need to check all the details of the complicated object inside.  You will still need to write code to collide the real object -- but it won't need to run thousands of times each frame...

Comment: It is. Sorry for not tagging as homework, this site is new for me. I know how to do collision for rectangle and circle and that was for previous homework. Other than that, i tried to do pixel perfect collision but then i realised that it is going to be more difficult to implement in my current code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on computer graphics, but generally your problem boils down to determining whether a dot is inside a convex polygon or not.

For this, I would use the following simple technique. There is a function called vector product, which helps to determine if the rotation direction from one vector to another is positive or negative. So, your check for whether a point X is inside rhombus formed by a polygon A_1, A_2, ..., A_n is just to check whether all the vector products (A_iA_{i+1}, A_iX) have the same sign.

Vector product of vectors (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) is defined as x1 * y2 - x2 * y1.

Now, your detection goes on like this: if the previous position is outside the polygon, and the current is inside, than the dot has hit the polygon. In order to determine, which side was crossed, you just have to check which of the signs of vector products (A_iA_{i+1}, A_iX) has changed since last position update.

Comment: I am sorry. I'm not quite sure if i understood what is what in (A_iA_{i+1}, A_iX) loop.

Comment: @Marko: `A_iA_{i+1}` is vector starting at `A_i` and finishing at `A_{i+1}`, the same is `A_iX`: vector from `A_i` to `X`. Next, you need to calculate the vector product of these vectors. You are doing this for all possible `i`. Then you check if all the signs of the products are the same.